# Gargage redundancy character at the end of original text when decrypt using Crypto++

Tags: c++, encryption, crypto++

I am using Crypto++, CTR mode, to encrypt and decrypt text in C++. Everything seem to worked 99%. Ecrypting success, decrypting is give back the original text too, but I given some extra random garbage redundancy text like 'ð', at the end of the decrypted text. This extra part is random generated each time I run the code. Is there something wrong in my code?

Encrypt a string to a string

```
string  encryptString(string plain, byte key[], int sizeKey, byte iv[], int sizeIV){
    string cipher;
    try{
        CTR_Mode< AES >::Encryption e;
        e.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeKey, iv, sizeIV);

        // The StreamTransformationFilter removes
        //  padding as required.
        StringSource s(plain, true,
            new StreamTransformationFilter(e,
                new StringSink(cipher)
                ) 
            ); 

#if 0
        StreamTransformationFilter filter(e);
        filter.Put((const byte*)plain.data(), plain.size());
        filter.MessageEnd();

        const size_t ret = filter.MaxRetrievable();
        cipher.resize(ret);
        filter.Get((byte*)cipher.data(), cipher.size());
#endif
        return cipher;
    }
    catch (const CryptoPP::Exception& e)
    {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Decrypt a ciphered string to a string

```
string  decryptString(string cipher, byte key[], int sizeKey, byte iv[], int sizeIV){
    string reco ="";
    try{
        CTR_Mode< AES >::Decryption d;
        d.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeKey, iv, sizeIV);

        StringSource s(cipher, true,
            new StreamTransformationFilter(d,
                new StringSink(reco)
                ) 
            ); 

    }
    catch (const CryptoPP::Exception& e)
    {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
    }
    return reco;

}
```

Wrap encryptString function above.

```
char* encrypt(char * plainText, byte key[], int sizeKey, byte iv[], int sizeIV, long &len){
    string cipher = encryptString(plainText, key, sizeKey, iv, sizeIV);
    len = cipher.size() + 1;
    char * writable = new  char[len];
    std::copy(cipher.begin(), cipher.end(), writable);
    writable[len] = '\0'; // don't forget the terminating 0
    return writable;
 }
```

Wrap decryptString function above.

```
char* decrypt(char * cipher,  byte key[], int sizeKey, byte iv[], int sizeIV, long len){
    string ss(cipher, len);
    long lengSS = ss.length();
    string recovered = decryptString(ss, key, sizeKey, iv, sizeIV);
    char * writable = new char[recovered.size() + 1];
    std::copy(recovered.begin(), recovered.end(), writable);
    writable[recovered.size()] = '\0'; // don't forget the terminating 0
    return writable;
}
```

My test script is simple. Read the some.txt content ("I love you"), write it to s1.txt to check if the reading is right. Encrypt, decrypt, then write the recovered text to another file (d1.txt).

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;

    byte key[AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8' };
    //prng.GenerateBlock(key, sizeof(key));

    byte iv[AES::BLOCKSIZE] = { '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1' };
    prng.GenerateBlock(iv, sizeof(iv));
    long size = 0;
    char * s1 = FileUtil::readAllByte("some.txt");
    //Result: s1.txt content is "I love you"

    long len = 0;
    char* result1 = encrypt(s1, key, sizeof(key), iv, sizeof(iv), len);
    //Result: result1 is a bunch of ciphered characters

    cout << "desc" << endl;
    char* recovered1 = decrypt(result1, key, sizeof(key), iv, sizeof(iv), len);
    //Result: recovered1="I love youð". Generally, it has form of "I love youX"
    //X can be any garbage chatacter, and each time I run the code, X is one different
    //character.
}
```

According to the accept answer, Solution is: updated my encrypt() like this:

```
char* encrypt(char * plainText, byte key[], int sizeKey, byte iv[], int sizeIV, long &len){
    string cipher = encryptString(plainText, key, sizeKey, iv, sizeIV);
    FileUtil::writeFile("ss1.txt", cipher, cipher.length());
    len = cipher.size() ;
     char * writable = new  char[len];
    std::copy(cipher.begin(), cipher.end(), writable);
    writable[len] = '\0'; // don't forget the terminating 0
    FileUtil::writeFile("w1.txt",writable, len);

    return writable;
}
```

Just allocate writeable's length = cipher's length. Set the terminator at `writeble[len]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tends to happen when you have things like buffer overruns and unterminated strings.  If we look at your `encrypt` function we see a buffer overrun:

```
len = cipher.size() + 1;
char * writable = new  char[len];
std::copy(cipher.begin(), cipher.end(), writable);
writable[len] = '\0';
```

See here you allocated `len` bytes, where `len` is one larger than `cipher`.  But when you terminate the string, you are using `len` to index which is out-of-bounds.

You should either use `len-1` or `cipher.size()` for the terminator index.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made two changes: first, allocate writeable = new char[len]; second, writable[len]='\0'. Its worked now :)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> char* encrypt(char * plainText, ... );
> char* decrypt(char * cipher, ... );
> ```

You can also avoid `encryptString` and `decryptString` and the extra copy. I'll show you the `encrypt`, the `decrypt` is similar.

```
char* encrypt(char * plainText, byte key[], int sizeKey, byte iv[], int sizeIV, long &len)
{
    const unsigned long plainTextLen = len; len = 0;
    const unsigned long extraLen = plainTextLen+16;

    ArraySource source(plainText, plainTextLen, false);
    unique_ptr<char[]> writable(new char[extraLen]);
    ArraySink sink(writable, extraLen);

    CTR_Mode< AES >::Encryption enc;
    enc.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeKey, iv, sizeIV);

    source.Detach(new StreamTransformationFilter(enc, new Redirector(sink)));
    source.PumpAll();

    len = sink.TotalPutLength();
    return writable.release();
}
```

I did not compile and run it, so you will have to clear the compiler issues in the code above. They should all be minor, like conversions and casts.

You usually don't need to worry about the `NULL`; just use the `ptr` and `len`. You can create a `std::string` from the decrypted ciphertext with `string recovered = string(ptr, len);`. `std::string` will produce a `NULL` when needed, but its usually not needed.

`Detach` is *not* a typo. You use it to `Attach` a new filter and `delete` a previous filter. You use it to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: I am testing your encrypt() function using Visual C++, syntax error at ArraySink sink(writable, extraLen); Because writable is char[], when the sink() required byte* type

Comment: @Andiana - *"I did not compile and run it, so you will have to clear the compiler issues in the code above. They should all be minor, like conversions and casts"*.  Cast the `char*` to `byte*`; and cast the `const char*` to a `const byte*`.

Comment: I am a bit confusing with unique_ptr, its seem to be best solution instead of char* or string, but I don't know how to use it in this case. Have I using writeble.get() to get its data?

Comment: @Andiana - My apologies that the help I have been trying to provide has not been helpful. Perhaps you should learn more about C++ before you continue with the Crypto++ library.